# How to make an image resize according to the screen size using HTML only?

Tags: html

Good afternoon, I am making a page layout using tables on HTML, but there's an issue that I'm stuck with. One of the instructions is that the images resizes according to the screen size, but I'm not allowed to use JS or CSS, only HTML. I have an idea on how to do it with CSS, but I'm not allowed to use it.

What I've tried until now is:
`<td width="35%" height="10%"><img src="https://blog.udacity.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/HTML_Blog-scaled.jpeg" width=100% height=100%></td>`

The problem is that the height in the `<td>` doesn't seem to change anything. The goal is that the image proportionally resizes, not getting like too thin or too large depending on the screen size.

Comment: Why can't you use CSS? And why did you change `table` to an `image` in your last edit??

Comment: @AlonEitan it is sort of a challenge :) and I changed those words because I only needed the images to resize.

Comment: I see. The problem with this challenge is that a correct solution will be to use CSS. I thought it might be a homework assignment

Comment: Yep. With CSS is something you can do in a flash, but with HTML only is giving me headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Mobile

```
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
    img {
        width: 50px;
        height : 50px;
    }
}
```

For Tablets

```
@media screen and (min-width: 540px) and (max-width: 780px) {
    img {
        
        width: 80px;
        height : 80px;
    }
}
```